# Time Complexity of an Algorithm

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

Here is problem in which we have to calculate the time complexity of given function

```
f(i) = 2*f(i+1) + 3*f(i+2)
For (int i=0; i < n; i++)
F[i] = 2*f[i+1]
```

What i think is the complexity of this algorithm is O(2^n) + O(n) which ultimately is O(2^n).
Please correct me if i am wrong?

Comment: What exactly do you want to calculate?. What is the input and the output? Any way here I can only see a simple loop, so it looks like O(n) Please, clarify the problem.

Comment: The way you presented the your question is not clear: `2 * f(i + 1)` means two recursive calls of `f(i + 1)` or literally `2` times the value returned by `f(i + 1)`?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, all the information you required to work these out in future is [here](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~vernon/cs367/notes/3.COMPLEXITY.html).

To answer your question. Because you have not provided a definition of f(i) in terms of I itself it is impossible to determine the actual complexity from what you have written above. However, in general for loops like

```
for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    sequence of statements
}
```

executes N times, so the sequence of statements also executes N times. If we assume the statements are O(1), the total time for the for loop is N * O(1), which is O(N) overall. In your case above, if I take the liberty of re-writing it as

```
f(0) = 0;
f(1) = 1;
f(i+2) = 2*f(i+1) + 3*f(i)
for (int i=0; i < n; i++)
    f[i] = 2*f[i+2]
```

Then we have a well defined sequence of operations and it should be clear that the complexity for the n operations is, like the example I have given above, n * O(1), which is O(n).

I hope this helps.